# Snort custom log file from rule (logto) not working

Tags: snort

I am trying to create a custom Snort rule which outputs a log file whenever it is triggered. My rule is as follows:

`log tcp $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg: "Facebook Accessed"; content:"www.facebook.com"; logto:"facebook.log"; content:"www.facebook.com"; threshold: type limit, track by_dst, count:1, seconds:60;`

And I call Snort with the following command:

`snort -A console -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -l /var/log/snort`

However, there is no `facebook.log` file being created. I can see all the `snort.log` files, and an alert of the same rule is working just fine. I have given permissions to the user `snort` to write to `/var/log/snort`.

What am I missing?